# Почему из аргументов вычитываются минус один?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void go_south_east(int *lat, int *lon){
    *lat -= 1;
    *lon += 1;
}

int main(){
    int latitude = 32;
    int longitude = -64;
    go_south_east(&latitude, &longitude);
    printf("стоп теперь наши координаты [%i %i]\n", latitude, longitude);
    return 0;
}
```

Перед вами кусок кода из игры обходной корабль.Представляю вам ту часть которую мне не ясно.Тут функции go_south_east передается 2 параметра lat и lon первый вычитывает второй добавляет.
Вопрос такой.
Почему при добавления аргументов оба они вычитывают а не добавляют ?То есть вместо значение 31 -65 получаем результат 31 -63 почему так происходит.

Comment: Э..., сначала вы пишете `первый вычитывает второй добавляет`, а потом `Почему при добавления аргументов оба они вычитывают`,  немного противоречивый вопрос, или вы не знаете что `-64 + 1 = -63`?

Comment: @fghj да сори я вспомнил. Я просто забыл элементарную вещь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**СКАНДАЛЫ ИНТРИГИ РАССЛЕДОВАНИЯ!**

```
-64 + 1 = -63
```

Арифметика, 5 класс средней школы.